# How to make audio only play when it is added to a playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you run the code and go to the end of the very first song you will notice that it automatically goes to the next song. I only want it to go to the next song if the add to playlist button is clicked, if it is not clicked I want it to skip right over it. Someone please help me, it would be much appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle_container").hide();
  $("button.reveal").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Add to Playlist') {
      $(this).text('Remove from playlist');
    } else {
      $("#audioPlayer")[0].pause();
      $("#audioPlayer")[0].currentTime = 0;
      $(this).text('Add to Playlist');
    }

    return false;
  });
  $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".reveal").click();
});
```

```css
#searchbar {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%
}

#playlist .current-song a {
  color: #7777FE;
  border-color: #008ae6;
}

#playlist {
  list-style: none;
}

#playlist li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ca0ce0;
}


#playlist {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: blue;
}

.animals {
  display: list-item;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

}

#background {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#background2 {
  border: solid;
  width: 98%;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#background3 {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}


#playlist.current-song {
  border-color: #008ae6;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  float: left
}

#song {
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: left;
}

.artist {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.image3 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true" controls="true">
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
    <li class="animals"><a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355309/Swing_Jazz_Drum.mp3"><div id="background3"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575489560633-6a7609328e67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" class="image3"/><h4 id="song">Freedom Reign</h4><h5 class="artist">Abt Goat</h5></div></a></li>

      <button class="reveal">Add to Playlist </button>
      <div class="toggle_container">
        <div class="block">
          <li class="current-song"><a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355309/Swing_Jazz_Drum.mp3">
              <div id="background2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577044685231-70e99274404c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80Cat" class="image" />
                <h4 id="song">Tummy Why</h4>
                <h5 class="artist">Revy Conover</h5>
              </div>
            </a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <script>
      audioPlayer();

      function audioPlayer() {
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
          $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
          $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
          currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
          $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
        });
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function() {
          currentSong++;
          if (currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
            currentSong = 0;
          $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
          $("#playlist li:eq(" + currentSong + ")").addClass("current-song");
          $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
          $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        });
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: do u need to repeatedly loop the song.

Comment: @Ramyz I’m not sure what you mean by repeatedly loop the song. If you mean why do I have to play the same song over and over that is only because I’m testing it out using the same song. It’s not actually the same song being looped over and over it is different divs that play the same song. If you press add to playlist and go to the end of the first song you will see the blue writing switch to the second song, the blue represents the current song, does this make sense?

Comment: what i mean is, there 2 songs, song1 & song2, if the user click song1 that song will be played over and over like loop and if the user adds the song2 it should play song1 and song2 and keep looping one song after another. right ???

Comment: @Ramyz That is what I want to happen although if you go to the end of the first song you will notice the 2nd song play wether the add to playlist button is clicked or not

Comment: the way in your code to add as playlist is not good to what your needs. i got very interested in this so will give a try and submit and answer with new way that works..

Comment: @Ramyz thank you very much, also you should get a lot of reputation when you solve this because clearly I am not the only one who is this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, i made a lot of changes.

The best way to make a playlist was, making a list with Array!

Now ....

- First song will keep repeating over until a new songs is added
- if the second song is added it will repeat one after another.
- You can add song and remove them (if the removed song is playing now it will skip to nest song automatically.
- You can play any song by clicking on the song detail box in the added "Your Playlist".

Hope you like this modification.

```js
var APlayer = $('audio#audioPlayer')[0];
var AP_PlayList = [];
var currentTrack = 0;

// play clicking a Song in YourPlaylist
$('body').on("click", '.AudioSong', function(e) {
  var trackID = $(this).attr('id');
  index = AP_PlayList.findIndex(x => x.id === trackID);
  console.log(index + "::" + trackID);
  audioPlayer(index);
});

// in the end of each song load next song in the arraylist and play
$('#audioPlayer').on('ended', function() {
  NextSong();
});

function audioPlayer(TrackNum){
  var APlayer = $('audio#audioPlayer')[0];  // Get AudioPlayer element
  APlayer.setAttribute("trackid", AP_PlayList[TrackNum]['id']);  //set Current Playing song TrackID to player
  APlayer.setAttribute("src", AP_PlayList[TrackNum]['link']);  //set Current Playing song Link/Path to player
  console.log("Started Track " + AP_PlayList[TrackNum]['id']);
  APlayer.loop = false;  // Set Player not to loop songs. so $('#audioPlayer').on('ended', function can be detected
  APlayer.load();  // Load player and play the song set
  // NowPlaying song in YourPlaylist
  $('span#nowplaying').html("&nbsp;");  // Clear all NowPlaying
  $('#your_playlist div#list').find('div#'+ AP_PlayList[TrackNum]['id'] + ' span#nowplaying').html(" &#8250; Now Playing");  // Set NowPlaying to current playing song
}

function NextSong(){
  var APlayer = $('audio#audioPlayer')[0];
  // Check Array song list lenght
  if (AP_PlayList.length > 0) {  // if songs exisxt in array list 
    console.log("Ended Track " + AP_PlayList[currentTrack]['id']);
    currentTrack++; // get next song's track number
    if(currentTrack > AP_PlayList.length-1) { currentTrack = 0 } // loop the playlist if it last song
    audioPlayer(currentTrack); // play next song
  } else { // if songs array list is empty
    $('#your_playlist div#list div').remove(); // Clean the YourPlaylist 
    $('small#nosongs').fadeIn(); // Show No Songs massage in YourPlaylist
    APlayer.pause(); // Stop current playing song
    APlayer.setAttribute("src", ''); // Remove current playing song from player
    APlayer.load(); // Reload Player
  }
}

// When Remove from Playlist Button Clicked
$('body').on("click", '.removetrack', function(e) {
  var TrackID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  // Remove the song from Array songlist
  $.each(AP_PlayList, function(i, el){
    if (this.id == TrackID){
      AP_PlayList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  //Chk if the removed song is playing
  var APlayer = $('audio#audioPlayer')[0];
  var PlayingTrackID = APlayer.getAttribute("trackid");
  if (PlayingTrackID === TrackID) { 
    NextSong(); // if the removed song is playing skip to next song
  }
  $('#your_playlist div#list div#' + TrackID).remove();  // remove the song from "YourPlaylist"
  $('.addtrack.'+TrackID).fadeIn();  //  Show Add to playlist Button
  $('.removetrack.'+TrackID).fadeOut();  // Hide Remove from playlist Button
});

// When Add to Playlist Button Clicked
$('body').on("click", '.addtrack', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var TrackID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var TrackLink = $(this).attr('data-src');
  // check if array is empty
  if (AP_PlayList.length > 0) { // if not empty
    // get the object form the array songlist that macht TrackID
    var emps = $.grep(AP_PlayList, function(n, i) {
      return n.id === TrackID;
    });
    if (emps.length == 0 || emps[0].id != TrackID) { // if song is not in array songlist then add this song to array songlist
      AP_PlayList.push({
        id: TrackID,
        link: TrackLink
      });
      updateHTMLlist(); // add new song and update YourPlaylist
    }
  } else {  // if array is blank then add this song to array list
    AP_PlayList.push({
      id: TrackID, 
      link:  TrackLink
    });
    updateHTMLlist(); // add new song and update YourPlaylist
  }   
  console.log(AP_PlayList);
  function updateHTMLlist() {
    // Creating Selected YourPlaylist Part
    var getSongDetails = $("ul").find(`[data-trackID='${TrackID}']`).html(); // get songs info from UL list item
    $('small#nosongs').fadeOut();
    $('#your_playlist div#list').append('<div class="AudioSong" id="' + TrackID + '">' + getSongDetails + '</div>');
    $('<button class="removetrack active" data-id="'+ TrackID +'">Remove from Playlist</button>').appendTo('div#'+ TrackID);

  }
  //Load player if its not playing 
  if (APlayer.paused) {
    audioPlayer(0);
  }
  $(this).parent().find('.removetrack').fadeIn(); // Show Remove from playlist Button
  $(this).fadeOut(); // Hide Add to playlist Button
});
```

```css
#searchbar {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%
}

#playlist .current-song a {
  color: #7777FE;
  border-color: #008ae6;
}

#playlist {
  list-style: none;
}

#playlist li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ca0ce0;
}

#playlist {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: blue;
}

.animals {
  display: list-item;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#background {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#background2 {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#background3 {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div#your_playlist {
  background-color: rgba(239,239,239,0.68);
}

div#your_playlist .AudioSong{
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid rgba(39,200,184,0.79);
  width: 300px;
}

div#your_playlist .AudioSong:hover{
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,176,5,1.00);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#playlist.current-song {
  border-color: #008ae6;
}

.image {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#song {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.artist {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.image3 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
}

button.removetrack{
  display: none;
}

button.active{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#nowplaying{
  animation:blinkingText 0.5s infinite;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
  0%{     color: rgba(0,0,0,0.00); }
  25%{    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25); }
  50%{    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50); }
  75%{    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); }
  100%{   color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio style="width: 100%" id="audioPlayer" preload="true" controls="true" autoplay></audio>
    <div id="your_playlist">
     <h3>Your Playlist</h3>
     <div id="list">
      <small id="nosongs">No Songs found ! Add songs to playlist,<br></small>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <h3>Avaibale Song List</h3>
    <ul id="playlist">
     <li class="track" id="track1">
   <div id="background3" class="background" data-trackID="1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575489560633-6a7609328e67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" class="image"/>
    <h4 id="song">&nbsp;Freedom Reign</h4>
    <h5 class="artist">&nbsp;Abt Goat</h5>
    <span id="nowplaying">&nbsp;</span>
   </div>
   <button class="addtrack 1" data-id="1" data-src="https://archive.org/download/slac2002-02-15/slac2002-02-15d1t07_64kb.mp3">Add to Playlist</button>
   <button class="removetrack 1" data-id="1">Remove from Playlist</button>
       </li>
  <li class="track" id="track2">
   <div id="background2" class="background" data-trackID="2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577044685231-70e99274404c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80Cat" class="image" />
    <h4 id="song">&nbsp;Tummy Why</h4>
    <h5 class="artist">&nbsp;Revy Conover</h5>
    <span id="nowplaying">&nbsp;</span>
   </div>
   <button class="addtrack 2" data-id="2" data-src="https://archive.org/download/ra2007-07-21/ra2007-07-21d1t05_64kb.mp3">Add to Playlist</button>
   <button class="removetrack 2" data-id="2">Remove from Playlist</button>
  </li>
    </ul>
```